# Shell script-How to return maximum value in array?

Tags: shell-script, array, bash-array

I have a array:

```
ARRAY=(12.5 6.2)
```

I wish to return the maximum value in ARRAY which **Output is 12.5**

Anyone can share me ideas?

I have try this:

```
max=0
for v in ${ARRAY[@]}; do
    if (( $v > $max )); then max=$v; fi; 
done
echo $max
```

But it return me:

```
((: 12.5 > 0 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5 > 0 ")
((: 6.2 > 0 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2 > 0 ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf '%s\n' "${ARRAY[@]}" |
awk '$1 > m || NR == 1 { m = $1 } END { print m }'
```

Since the `bash` shell does not do floating point arithmetics, it's easier to compare floating point numbers in another language.  Here I'm using `awk` to find the maximum of all the elements in the `ARRAY` array.

The `printf` command will output each element of the array on its own line and the `awk` code will update its `m` value to be the maximum of the values seen so far.  At the end, the `m` value is printed.

The test on `NR == 1` will be true on for the first line read by the `awk` program and would initialise the value of `m` to the first value of the array (something that you fail to do, which means that your code would have returned `0` for an array with all negative numbers, had it worked).

Comment: Possible alternative to `|| NR == 1`: set `m` to array's first element using `-v m="${ARRAY}"`

Comment: Can your function here store in a variable?

Comment: @ShiJieTio I'm using no function, but the result may be stored in a variable using a standard command substitution as usual: `max=$( printf ... | awk ... )`.

Comment: for example:
Result= "%s\n' "${ARRAY[@]}" |awk '$1 > m || m == "" { m = $1 } END { print m }"

Comment: @ShiJieTio No. You left out the `printf` and the `$( ... )` bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do floating point arithmetics, you'd need to switch to ksh93, zsh or yash (or `fish` if you're ready to wander away from Bourne-like shells), `bash` doesn't support them.

For a syntax compatible to all 3 shells:

```
max() {
  [ "$#" -gt 0 ] || return
  typeset i max="$1"; shift
  for i do
    if [ "$((i > max))" -ne 0 ]; then
      max=$i
    fi
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$max"
}
array=(12.5 6.2 nan 0xfff -inf inf -1e12 1e20)
max "${array[@]}"
```

(you need a recent version of `zsh` for `inf`/`nan` to be supported. Variations in case are supported in all 3 (`INF`, `NaN`, `Inf`...), but only `yash` supports alternative spellings like `Infinity`; `0x12p34` types of numbers are not supported by `zsh` yet. Beware that whether `010` means 10 or 8 depends on the shell and its configuration)